# Can we turn on/off hdmi settings from our app programmatically

Tags: android, settings, hdmi

I want to load hdmi settings (check box Turn on HDMI, HDMI Resolution Selection dialog box) in my custom app activity. And if I change these settings in my custom app the settings will be changed in actual device settings. Is it possible?

Thanks any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are unique to your device -- normal Android devices with HDMI support (e.g., Nexus 10) do not have such settings. Hence, please call your device manufacturer and ask them if they have an API for such settings.